# Laravel 5: Download file not show popup for save

Tags: laravel, file, download

In my Laravel 5.3, I uploaded file to "uploads/files/file.pdf". When I try to download it, the file is found using "file_exists" function but there is no popup window to save the file into the local computer. Note: I removed "public" folder from url by moving files to sub-directory called "local".

Please advice what is wrong.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Response;

...............................

public function getDownload()
{
    $file= "uploads/files/file.pdf";

    echo $file;

    if(file_exists($file)){
        dd('File is exists.');
    }else{
        dd('File is not exists.');
    }        

    $headers = array('Content-Type: application/pdf',);
    return Response::download($file, 'filename.pdf', $headers);
}
```

Comment: once clear your browser cache and try again

Comment: Try `$file = public_path() .  "/uploads/files/file.pdf";`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need one more header to tell browser to open the file or to download it.

So to download it in browser use

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');
```

To open it in browser use

```
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf");
```

In your example you should have your `$header` variable like

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/pdf','Content-Disposition: inline; filename=filename.pdf');
```

or

```
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/pdf','Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');
```

Personally I use it like below

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length:" . strlen($file));
//header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=file.pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.pdf"');
print $file;
```

Or maybe just in your case do it like below

```
return response()->download("uploads/files/file.pdf");
```

Whole controller code is below

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Response;

...............................

public function getDownload()
{
    $file= "uploads/files/file.pdf";

    //echo $file;

    if(file_exists($file)){
        //dd('File is exists.');
        return response()->download($file);

    }else{
        //dd('File is not exists.');
        abort(404);
    }  
}
```

Comment: I use each of them but it is still not working.
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/pdf','Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"');
        return Response::download($file, 'filename.pdf', $headers);

Comment: @Naren I'v updated my answer on how i do it. Have you tried maybe just `return response()->download($pathToFile);` or `return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);`

Comment: Still not working. Could you write the complete Controller and function?

Comment: It is fixed now. I use barryvdh/laravel-dompdf to generate pdf from view and save it. Thank you for all answers.

Comment: @Naren If this helped you then accept it as answer. If you have your own solution please provide for further use.